# How to delete comma from the end of results?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I use ACF advanced custom field to add a custom field "authors" to "articles" post type. Authors field is a relationship field which relate Articles post type with Authors post type.
I want to display the values of this custom field in the form of : author one, author two
So, I found this code from ACF documentations:

```
<?php 
$posts = get_field('relationship_field_name');
if( $posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <span>Custom field from $post: <?php the_field('author'); ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But, this code display the result as a list. So, I tried to modify the code to be:

```
<?php 
$posts = get_field('author_name');
if( $posts ): 
    echo '' . ' <img src="aut.png" alt="authors" height="20" width="20">' . ' ' ;
?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>,         
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Actually, this code give me the result in the form I want (author one, author two,), but, I need to delete the comma ',' from the end of the result to be (author one, author two).
I know that i need to use `echo rtrim($post,' ,')` function, but I couldn't figure out how.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a WordPress question, but since you're using the Loop, a lot of people will assume it's WordPress-specific. That being said, the solution is to use PHP's native array-to-string conversion utilities.

Instead of the code you do have, you'll want to use something like:

```
<?php 
$posts = get_field( 'author_name' );
if ( $posts ) {
    echo '&nbsp;<img src="aut.png" alt="authors" height="20" width="20">&nbsp;';

    $post_list = array();
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) { // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $post_list[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_the_permalink() ), esc_html( get_the_title() ) );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly

    echo implode( ', ', $post_list );

}
```

Very briefly, this updates your original code to do a few things:

- It uses the `&nbsp;` HTML entity instead of attempting to concatenate a strings with extra spaces (more performant)
- It builds up an array of post entries and uses PHP's native [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join the entries together with commas.
- It uses `sprintf()` to make the post entry generation a bit cleaner
- It uses proper escaping for the permalink and the post title to prevent stored XSS vulnerabilities

Again, these changes are vanilla PHP, we just happen to be using a WordPress loop and WordPress template tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. thanks for the detailed helpful answer.

Comment: Another question please. Can i replace the last comma in (author one, author two, author three) with '&' to be (author one, author two & author three)?